# Modifying single occurrence from recurring series is not reflected in the data read from the Rest API

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

When you create occurring event in Office365 Outlook and modify any single occurrence (edit occurrence) the change is never reflected in the data consumed from the REST API. Both recurrence exception is not created (new event) and series master has no single field changed.

Expected behavior is the SeriesMaster to contain list of exceptions (for example by dates), and each exception to be created as new separate event with link to the recurrence head (e.g.: SeriesMasterId).

```
{
    "@odata.id ": "https: //outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('----')",
    "@odata.etag": "----",
    "Id": "----",
    "ChangeKey": "----",
    "Categories": [],
    "DateTimeCreated": "2015-05-27T13:36:11.9330924Z",
    "DateTimeLastModified": "2015-05-27T13:44:16.2212804Z",
    "Subject": "EVRY DAY INTERVAL WITH EXCEPTIONS",
    "BodyPreview": "",
    "Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML",
        "Content": "Example content"
    },
    "Importance": "Normal",
    "HasAttachments": false,
    "Start": "2015-04-28T00:00:00Z",
    "StartTimeZone": "UTC",
    "End": "2015-04-29T00:00:00Z",
    "EndTimeZone": "UTC",
    "Reminder": null,
    "Location": {
        "DisplayName": "",
        "Address": {
            "Street": "",
            "City": "",
            "State": "",
            "CountryOrRegion": "",
            "PostalCode": ""
        },
        "Coordinates": {
            "Accuracy": "NaN",
            "Altitude": "NaN",
            "AltitudeAccuracy": "NaN",
            "Latitude": "NaN",
            "Longitude": "NaN"
        }
    },
    "ResponseStatus": {
        "Response": "Organizer",
        "Time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "ShowAs": "Free",
    "IsAllDay": true,
    "IsCancelled": false,
    "IsOrganizer": true,
    "ResponseRequested": true,
    "Type": "SeriesMaster",
    "SeriesMasterId": null,
    "Attendees": [],
    "Recurrence": {
        "Pattern": {
            "Type": "Daily",
            "Interval": 2,
            "Month": 0,
            "Index": "First",
            "FirstDayOfWeek": "Sunday",
            "DayOfMonth": 0
        },
        "Range": {
            "Type": "NoEnd",
            "StartDate": "2015-04-28T00:00:00+03:00",
            "EndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "NumberOfOccurrences": 0
        }
    },
    "Organizer": {
        "EmailAddress": {
            "Address": "----",
            "Name": "----"
        }
    },
    "iCalUId": "----",
    "WebLink": "----"
}
```

Can anyone shred some light on this? Currently the whole Recurrence object consumed from the Rest API looks (apologize for that) incomplete and useless (but I'm hitting a road blocks on each step).

Also is there any place where I can directly report issues to the dev team of the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceptions and occurrences aren't actually exposed in the `Recurrence` object. In order to see individual occurrences or exceptions, you need to use the [CalendarView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#GeteventsGetacalendarviewREST) endpoint. This causes Exchange to expand recurring events for the time window specified, and it returns individual occurrences or exceptions. This is necessary because the individual occurrences/exceptions do not exist on the calendar as actual events, they are derived from the series master. If you just do a GET on `/Me/Events`, you never see them!

For example, I created a recurring event on my calendar, then I modified one occurrence to be at a different time (which makes it an exception).

Doing a GET on `/Me/Events`:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Me/Events",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('jason@johnstonian.onmicrosoft.com')/Events('AAMkADRmMDExYzhjLWYyNGMtNDZmMC1iZDU4LTRkMjk4YTdjMjU5OABGAAAAAABp4MZ-5xP3TJnNAPmjsRslBwAoPBSqxXQOT6tuE0pxCMrtAAAAAAENAAAoPBSqxXQOT6tuE0pxCMrtAAC5xYC1AAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"KDwUqsV0Dk+rbhNKcQjK7QAAucdOPw==\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADRmMDExYzhjLWYyNGMtNDZmMC1iZDU4LTRkMjk4YTdjMjU5OABGAAAAAABp4MZ-5xP3TJnNAPmjsRslBwAoPBSqxXQOT6tuE0pxCMrtAAAAAAENAAAoPBSqxXQOT6tuE0pxCMrtAAC5xYC1AAA=",
      "ChangeKey": "KDwUqsV0Dk+rbhNKcQjK7QAAucdOPw==",
      "Categories": [],
      "DateTimeCreated": "2015-05-28T13:39:06.310974Z",
      "DateTimeLastModified": "2015-05-28T13:39:21.0300106Z",
      "Subject": "Exception test",
      "BodyPreview": "​",
      "Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML",
        "Content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<style type=\"text/css\" style=\"display:none;\"><!-- P {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;} --></style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir=\"ltr\">\r\n<div id=\"divtagdefaultwrapper\" style=\"font-size:12pt;color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;\">\r\n<p>​<br>\r\n</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
      },
      "Importance": "Normal",
      "HasAttachments": false,
      "Start": "2015-05-28T20:00:00Z",
      "StartTimeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
      "End": "2015-05-28T20:30:00Z",
      "EndTimeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
      "Reminder": 15,
      "Location": {
        "DisplayName": "My Office",
        "Address": {
          "Street": "",
          "City": "",
          "State": "",
          "CountryOrRegion": "",
          "PostalCode": ""
        },
        "Coordinates": {
          "Accuracy": "NaN",
          "Altitude": "NaN",
          "AltitudeAccuracy": "NaN",
          "Latitude": "NaN",
          "Longitude": "NaN"
        }
      },
      "ResponseStatus": {
        "Response": "Organizer",
        "Time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "ShowAs": "Busy",
      "IsAllDay": false,
      "IsCancelled": false,
      "IsOrganizer": true,
      "ResponseRequested": true,
      "Type": "SeriesMaster",
      "SeriesMasterId": null,
      "Attendees": [],
      "Recurrence": {
        "Pattern": {
          "Type": "Daily",
          "Interval": 1,
          "Month": 0,
          "Index": "First",
          "FirstDayOfWeek": "Sunday",
          "DayOfMonth": 0
        },
        "Range": {
          "Type": "EndDate",
          "StartDate": "2015-05-28T00:00:00-04:00",
          "EndDate": "2015-06-04T00:00:00-04:00",
          "NumberOfOccurrences": 0
        }
      },
      "Organizer": {
        "EmailAddress": {
          "Address": "jason@johnstonian.onmicrosoft.com",
          "Name": "Jason Johnston"
        }
      },
      "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000006CACEEAA4B99D0010000000000000000100000009478C61D36C90847B5F3C126ACB0A17E",
      "WebLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADRmMDExYzhjLWYyNGMtNDZmMC1iZDU4LTRkMjk4YTdjMjU5OABGAAAAAABp4MZ%2F5xP3TJnNAPmjsRslBwAoPBSqxXQOT6tuE0pxCMrtAAAAAAENAAAoPBSqxXQOT6tuE0pxCMrtAAC5xYC1AAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ICalendarItemDetailsViewModelFactory"
    }
  ]
}
```

Doing a GET on `/Me/CalendarView` for the day on which the exception falls (note the `"Type": "Exception"` field):

```
GET /Me/CalendarView?startDateTime=2015-05-30T04:00:00Z&endDateTime=2015-05-31T04:00:00Z

{
  "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('jason@johnstonian.onmicrosoft.com')/Events('AAMkADRmMDExYzhjLWYyNGMtNDZmMC1iZDU4LTRkMjk4YTdjMjU5OAFRAAgI0miCtL1AAEYAAAAAaeDGf_cT90yZzQD5o7EbJQcAKDwUqsV0Dk_rbhNKcQjK7QAAAAABDQAAKDwUqsV0Dk_rbhNKcQjK7QAAucWAtQAAEA==')",
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"KDwUqsV0Dk+rbhNKcQjK7QAAucdOPw==\"",
  "Id": "AAMkADRmMDExYzhjLWYyNGMtNDZmMC1iZDU4LTRkMjk4YTdjMjU5OAFRAAgI0miCtL1AAEYAAAAAaeDGf_cT90yZzQD5o7EbJQcAKDwUqsV0Dk_rbhNKcQjK7QAAAAABDQAAKDwUqsV0Dk_rbhNKcQjK7QAAucWAtQAAEA==",
  "ChangeKey": "KDwUqsV0Dk+rbhNKcQjK7QAAucdOPw==",
  "Categories": [],
  "DateTimeCreated": "2015-05-28T13:39:20.9676251Z",
  "DateTimeLastModified": "2015-05-28T13:39:20.9676252Z",
  "Subject": "Exception test",
  "BodyPreview": "​",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<style type=\"text/css\" style=\"display:none;\"><!-- P {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;} --></style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir=\"ltr\">\r\n<div id=\"divtagdefaultwrapper\" style=\"font-size:12pt;color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;\">\r\n<p>​<br>\r\n</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
  },
  "Importance": "Normal",
  "HasAttachments": false,
  "Start": "2015-05-30T20:30:00Z",
  "StartTimeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
  "End": "2015-05-30T21:00:00Z",
  "EndTimeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
  "Reminder": 15,
  "Location": {
    "DisplayName": "My Office",
    "Address": {
      "Street": "",
      "City": "",
      "State": "",
      "CountryOrRegion": "",
      "PostalCode": ""
    },
    "Coordinates": {
      "Accuracy": "NaN",
      "Altitude": "NaN",
      "AltitudeAccuracy": "NaN",
      "Latitude": "NaN",
      "Longitude": "NaN"
    }
  },
  "ResponseStatus": {
    "Response": "Organizer",
    "Time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "ShowAs": "Busy",
  "IsAllDay": false,
  "IsCancelled": false,
  "IsOrganizer": true,
  "ResponseRequested": true,
  "Type": "Exception",
  "SeriesMasterId": "AAMkADRmMDExYzhjLWYyNGMtNDZmMC1iZDU4LTRkMjk4YTdjMjU5OABGAAAAAABp4MZ-5xP3TJnNAPmjsRslBwAoPBSqxXQOT6tuE0pxCMrtAAAAAAENAAAoPBSqxXQOT6tuE0pxCMrtAAC5xYC1AAA=",
  "Attendees": [],
  "Recurrence": null,
  "Organizer": {
    "EmailAddress": {
      "Address": "jason@johnstonian.onmicrosoft.com",
      "Name": "Jason Johnston"
    }
  },
  "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00807DF051E6CACEEAA4B99D0010000000000000000100000009478C61D36C90847B5F3C126ACB0A17E",
  "WebLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADRmMDExYzhjLWYyNGMtNDZmMC1iZDU4LTRkMjk4YTdjMjU5OAFRAAgI0miCtL1AAEYAAAAAaeDGf%2BcT90yZzQD5o7EbJQcAKDwUqsV0Dk%2BrbhNKcQjK7QAAAAABDQAAKDwUqsV0Dk%2BrbhNKcQjK7QAAucWAtQAAEA%3D%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ICalendarItemDetailsViewModelFactory"
}
```

Also, this is a great forum for reporting issues directly to us. As long as your tagging with `outlook-restapi`, we'll see it! :)

Comment: Thank you for your time :) I actually already realized that the recurring event exceptions are loaded by requesting instances of an event ("events/{0}/instances..") and start implementing it. As an idea (most probably it's not applicable in your case due to backward compatibility) it will be a much better to handle the recurrence exceptions as follows:
1) Recurrence head to contain 
"recurrenceException" - array of dates in which the series should not be rendred

2) On creating exception, update the head field with the ex. date and create new event which contains the point to head by id.

Comment: This way:
1) The Deleted exceptions will be just dates in the head.
2) The Updated exceptions can be loaded like regular events with the initial request (you will know the event is exception if the "SeriesMasterId" is not 0/null). This way you will have solution for the case when you have e.g. 1000 recurring events with exceptions and you need to make 1000 requests to the API for the exceptions.