# How to know which occurrence of recurring event has been removed?

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi

My app has subscription to office365 calendar called ConferenceRoom. So when event is created/modified/deleted office365 servers will send notification to my application that something of those three happened.

In the calendar I create recurring event *standup meeting* for every monday (via browser). After this my app gets notification with `ChangeType: Created` and here is the recurring part of that notification's event:

```
Recurrence:
 { Pattern:
    { Type: 'Weekly',
      Interval: 1,
      Month: 0,
      DayOfMonth: 0,
      DaysOfWeek: [Object],
      FirstDayOfWeek: 'Sunday',
      Index: 'First' },
   Range:
    { Type: 'NoEnd',
      StartDate: '2016-09-12',
      EndDate: '0001-01-01',
      RecurrenceTimeZone: 'FLE Standard Time',
      NumberOfOccurrences: 0 } },
```

And the whole data of that event (id got from the notification):

```
{ '@odata.context': 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Users(\'2ce6a929-0b04-40fb-9c73-d812370e0d46%40ea38f869-d755-40c7-9c95-e6277325b7ae\')/Events/$entity',
  '@odata.id': 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users(\'2ce6a929-0b04-40fb-9c73-d812370e0d46@ea38f869-d755-40c7-9c95-e6277325b7ae\')/Events(\'AAMkADg5YzZmNTViLWM3NjEtNGI4Mi04Yjg4LTkyOWQ4NjFjM2QzOABGAAAAAAATT-M8JoV8TI5B1BhmG2N_BwBi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAAAAFZAABi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAMNRbUAAA=\')',
  '@odata.etag': 'W/"Yt2KqvrIzEmHRx7sfmlFxQAADDdF3g=="',
  Id: 'AAMkADg5YzZmNTViLWM3NjEtNGI4Mi04Yjg4LTkyOWQ4NjFjM2QzOABGAAAAAAATT-M8JoV8TI5B1BhmG2N_BwBi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAAAAFZAABi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAMNRbUAAA=',
  CreatedDateTime: '2016-09-13T03:55:43.5305953-02:00',
  LastModifiedDateTime: '2016-09-13T03:55:43.5476101-02:00',
  ChangeKey: 'Yt2KqvrIzEmHRx7sfmlFxQAADDdF3g==',
  Categories: [],
  OriginalStartTimeZone: 'FLE Standard Time',
  OriginalEndTimeZone: 'FLE Standard Time',
  ResponseStatus: { Response: 'Organizer', Time: '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z' },
  iCalUId: '040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000F9B6FC76830DD2010000000000000000100000005D7D5B0B8D1EA84E86C8AEE4014697CA',
  ReminderMinutesBeforeStart: 15,
  IsReminderOn: true,
  HasAttachments: false,
  Subject: 'standup meeting',
  Body:
   { ContentType: 'HTML',
     Content: '<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\r\n<meta content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">\r\n<style type="text/css" style="display:none">\r\n<!--\r\np\r\n\t{margin-top:0;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir="ltr">\r\n<div id="divtagdefaultwrapper" style="font-size:12pt; color:#000000; background-color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">\r\n<p><br>\r\n</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n' },
  BodyPreview: '',
  Importance: 'Normal',
  Sensitivity: 'Normal',
  Start:
   { DateTime: '2016-09-12T03:00:00.0000000',
     TimeZone: 'Etc/GMT+2' },
  End:
   { DateTime: '2016-09-12T03:30:00.0000000',
     TimeZone: 'Etc/GMT+2' },
  Location: { DisplayName: '', Address: {}, Coordinates: {} },
  IsAllDay: false,
  IsCancelled: false,
  IsOrganizer: true,
  Recurrence:
   { Pattern:
      { Type: 'Weekly',
        Interval: 1,
        Month: 0,
        DayOfMonth: 0,
        DaysOfWeek: [ 'Monday' ],
        FirstDayOfWeek: 'Sunday',
        Index: 'First' },
     Range:
      { Type: 'NoEnd',
        StartDate: '2016-09-12',
        EndDate: '0001-01-01',
        RecurrenceTimeZone: 'FLE Standard Time',
        NumberOfOccurrences: 0 } },
  ResponseRequested: false,
  SeriesMasterId: null,
  ShowAs: 'Busy',
  Type: 'SeriesMaster',
  Attendees: [],
  Organizer:
   { EmailAddress:
      { Name: 'John Smith',
        Address: 'john.smith@sample.onmicrosoft.com' } },
  WebLink: 'https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADg5YzZmNTViLWM3NjEtNGI4Mi04Yjg4LTkyOWQ4NjFjM2QzOABGAAAAAAATT%2FM8JoV8TI5B1BhmG2N%2BBwBi3Yqq%2BsjMSYdHHux%2BaUXFAAAAAAFZAABi3Yqq%2BsjMSYdHHux%2BaUXFAAAMNRbUAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewModel=ICalendarItemDetailsViewModelFactory',
  'Calendar@odata.associationLink': 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users(\'2ce6a929-0b04-40fb-9c73-d812370e0d46@ea38f869-d755-40c7-9c95-e6277325b7ae\')/Calendars(\'AAMkADg5YzZmNTViLWM3NjEtNGI4Mi04Yjg4LTkyOWQ4NjFjM2QzOABGAAAAAAATT-M8JoV8TI5B1BhmG2N_BwBi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAAAAEGAABi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAAAA0jAAA=\')/$ref',
  'Calendar@odata.navigationLink': 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users(\'2ce6a929-0b04-40fb-9c73-d812370e0d46@ea38f869-d755-40c7-9c95-e6277325b7ae\')/Calendars(\'AAMkADg5YzZmNTViLWM3NjEtNGI4Mi04Yjg4LTkyOWQ4NjFjM2QzOABGAAAAAAATT-M8JoV8TI5B1BhmG2N_BwBi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAAAAEGAABi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAAAA0jAAA=\')' }
```

This is quite okay. Problem comes when I remove one occurrence of that event in the calendar. My app gets notification with `ChangeType: Updated` and body of that notification is pretty much same as when the event was created. There is no information about on what date that event was cancelled.

Data of the event when eventId got from `ChangeType: Updated` notification:

```
{ '@odata.context': 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Users(\'2ce6a929-0b04-40fb-9c73-d812370e0d46%40ea38f869-d755-40c7-9c95-e6277325b7ae\')/Events/$entity',
  '@odata.id': 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users(\'2ce6a929-0b04-40fb-9c73-d812370e0d46@ea38f869-d755-40c7-9c95-e6277325b7ae\')/Events(\'AAMkADg5YzZmNTViLWM3NjEtNGI4Mi04Yjg4LTkyOWQ4NjFjM2QzOABGAAAAAAATT-M8JoV8TI5B1BhmG2N_BwBi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAAAAFZAABi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAMNRbUAAA=\')',
  '@odata.etag': 'W/"Yt2KqvrIzEmHRx7sfmlFxQAADDdF3w=="',
  Id: 'AAMkADg5YzZmNTViLWM3NjEtNGI4Mi04Yjg4LTkyOWQ4NjFjM2QzOABGAAAAAAATT-M8JoV8TI5B1BhmG2N_BwBi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAAAAFZAABi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAMNRbUAAA=',
  CreatedDateTime: '2016-09-13T03:55:43.5305953-02:00',
  LastModifiedDateTime: '2016-09-13T03:57:48.2229052-02:00',
  ChangeKey: 'Yt2KqvrIzEmHRx7sfmlFxQAADDdF3w==',
  Categories: [],
  OriginalStartTimeZone: 'FLE Standard Time',
  OriginalEndTimeZone: 'FLE Standard Time',
  ResponseStatus: { Response: 'Organizer', Time: '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z' },
  iCalUId: '040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000F9B6FC76830DD2010000000000000000100000005D7D5B0B8D1EA84E86C8AEE4014697CA',
  ReminderMinutesBeforeStart: 15,
  IsReminderOn: true,
  HasAttachments: false,
  Subject: 'standup meeting',
  Body:
   { ContentType: 'HTML',
     Content: '<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\r\n<meta content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">\r\n<style type="text/css" style="display:none">\r\n<!--\r\np\r\n\t{margin-top:0;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir="ltr">\r\n<div id="divtagdefaultwrapper" style="font-size:12pt; color:#000000; background-color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">\r\n<p><br>\r\n</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n' },
  BodyPreview: '',
  Importance: 'Normal',
  Sensitivity: 'Normal',
  Start:
   { DateTime: '2016-09-12T03:00:00.0000000',
     TimeZone: 'Etc/GMT+2' },
  End:
   { DateTime: '2016-09-12T03:30:00.0000000',
     TimeZone: 'Etc/GMT+2' },
  Location: { DisplayName: '', Address: {}, Coordinates: {} },
  IsAllDay: false,
  IsCancelled: false,
  IsOrganizer: true,
  Recurrence:
   { Pattern:
      { Type: 'Weekly',
        Interval: 1,
        Month: 0,
        DayOfMonth: 0,
        DaysOfWeek: [ 'Monday' ],
        FirstDayOfWeek: 'Sunday',
        Index: 'First' },
     Range:
      { Type: 'NoEnd',
        StartDate: '2016-09-12',
        EndDate: '0001-01-01',
        RecurrenceTimeZone: 'FLE Standard Time',
        NumberOfOccurrences: 0 } },
  ResponseRequested: false,
  SeriesMasterId: null,
  ShowAs: 'Busy',
  Type: 'SeriesMaster',
  Attendees: [],
  Organizer:
   { EmailAddress:
      { Name: 'John Smith',
        Address: 'john.smith@sample.onmicrosoft.com' } },
  WebLink: 'https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADg5YzZmNTViLWM3NjEtNGI4Mi04Yjg4LTkyOWQ4NjFjM2QzOABGAAAAAAATT%2FM8JoV8TI5B1BhmG2N%2BBwBi3Yqq%2BsjMSYdHHux%2BaUXFAAAAAAFZAABi3Yqq%2BsjMSYdHHux%2BaUXFAAAMNRbUAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewModel=ICalendarItemDetailsViewModelFactory',
  'Calendar@odata.associationLink': 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users(\'2ce6a929-0b04-40fb-9c73-d812370e0d46@ea38f869-d755-40c7-9c95-e6277325b7ae\')/Calendars(\'AAMkADg5YzZmNTViLWM3NjEtNGI4Mi04Yjg4LTkyOWQ4NjFjM2QzOABGAAAAAAATT-M8JoV8TI5B1BhmG2N_BwBi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAAAAEGAABi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAAAA0jAAA=\')/$ref',
  'Calendar@odata.navigationLink': 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users(\'2ce6a929-0b04-40fb-9c73-d812370e0d46@ea38f869-d755-40c7-9c95-e6277325b7ae\')/Calendars(\'AAMkADg5YzZmNTViLWM3NjEtNGI4Mi04Yjg4LTkyOWQ4NjFjM2QzOABGAAAAAAATT-M8JoV8TI5B1BhmG2N_BwBi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAAAAEGAABi3Yqq_sjMSYdHHux_aUXFAAAAAA0jAAA=\')' }
```

Here is image to clear out what I exactly did in the calendar: [image]

Can you tell me how to know which occurrence of that event was removed?

This seems to be dead end, so any help would be appreciated.

**Just FYI:** recurring event has only one eventId and removing one occurrence of recurring event does NOT send notification with `ChangeType: DELETED`

Comment: Can you add the exact result of the `ChangeType: Updated` that you get when you delete the one occurrence?

Comment: @jehna1 Added event data after creation and after update.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but does this answer help you in any way?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484910/modifying-single-occurrence-from-recurring-series-is-not-reflected-in-the-data-r/30508731#30508731

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the API currently does not let you know which occurrence has been deleted. When you delete a single occurrence it does however trigger an update on the SeriesMaster. When this update comes in you will have to calculate when all meetings should occur and then fetch all occurrences. After iterating through the occurrences you can deduce which occurrence has been deleted from your earlier calculation. Since your meeting is recurring weekly forever, you'll want to restrict your timerange which you request occurrences from.

If using Python I can highly recommend the dateutil package which comes with a handy rrule class: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html

Comment: Okay, so you mean I have to fetch all events on those dates, when I assume that the recurring event should happen and then match, if this event exists on those days?

Comment: I think I've understand that, and that's correct, but to make sure here are the steps again below:
1. Upon receiving an update of the recurring meeting (the SeriesMaster), calculate all expected occurrences by looking at SeriesMaster["recurrence"].
2. Actually fetch all occurrences by making a GET request to /me/events/{event_id}/instances?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
3. Compare the list returned in 2 to the list you calculated in 1. Any missing occurrences from your second list are occurrences that have been deleted.