# How to get all occurrences and exceptions by Event id Using Outlook Rest API

Tags: office365, recurrence, outlook-restapi

We are using web-hooks to subscribe to changes (create/update/delete) in Outlook Events. When a recurring event is created in Outlook we get its Event ID. Using this Event ID we retrieve full Event object from Microsoft Graph API. Recurrence is included in the Event Object.

When we change this recurring event in Outlook to create an exception the web-hook sends the Event ID and status as 'updated'. We tried to retrieve full event object by this Event ID but there is nothing changed and there is no information about the exception.

Based on [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#GeteventsGetacalendarviewREST) and other [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484910/modifying-single-occurrence-from-recurring-series-is-not-reflected-in-the-data-r) we learned that we have to use Calendar View with a date range to get all occurrences and exceptions. But we do not know the date range, and we do not wish to see whole calendar view with other non related occurrences.

How can we get all Occurrences and Exceptions of an Event by the Event ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [list instances of a recurring event](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_list_instancesb). You have to give a time window for this query, so for events with no end date, it's effectively impossible to get "all" :).